# Automatically add some kind of text to text?

Tags: html, css, text

So basically this:

Is there a program or something where you can input text and then it automatically adds html tags at the beginning and end of the inputted text, for example:

I type the text: "Life finds a way"

Then the program makes it like this:

```
<p align="center">"Life finds a way"</p>
```

Matthew

Comment: Yes it can be done, but it would require more details on your requirement. From where is the text obtained (like text box/text area etc)? Where should the output be shown etc.

Comment: The text would be inputted in a textbox and then outputted in an text file?

Comment: Ok. Definitely cannot be done with just HTML and CSS. I guess you may need something like PHP. to write output to text file an I am not into it much.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [Markdown language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown#Example).

It's exactly what's used when you post something on StackOverflow. Everything you write is converted to html behind the scenes (that's also why you can't print a tag without using code notation in a post).

So simple text is converted to a `<p>` tag, unless you break two lines with an empty line.

To create an header, just use :

```
Header
------
```

which renders like this:

### Header

Or like this :

```
# Header
## Header
### Header
```

which renders :

## Header

### Header

#### Header

Creating lists is also very handy :

```
* first item
* second item
```

which renders :

- first item
- second item

or if you like numbered lists :

```
1. first item
2. second item
```

1. first item
2. second item

**Bold** is as simple as : `**Bold**`
*Italic* is : `*Italic*`

Finally, links are simple:

[The wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) is linked like this :

`[The wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)`

Comment: Link only answers are not encouraged in SO mate because they become of no-use when the linked page is lost.